# Imaginary unit $i$ is not a limit of a real Cauchy sequence

Tags: complex-numbers, cauchy-sequences, real-numbers

I saw this in some book once and it has been bugging me. The book had, I think as the first exercise it mentioned, to prove that the imaginary unit $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is not a limit of any real valued Cauchy sequence.

Given all I know of complex numbers, this shouldn't seem so hard to show. Like, I know any Cauchy sequence converges in $\mathbb R$ and elements of $\mathbb R$ have total ordering and elements of $\mathbb C$ cannot and so on, but still I have great doubts of how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: I think you should use the algebraic property that $i^2 = -1$ and that multiplication is continuous. In other words, without knowing about the complex numbers beforehand, you are supposed to show that there exists no Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ that converges to a number whose square is $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $a_n$ is real, then the distance from $a_n$ to $i$ is $\sqrt{a_n^2+1}$, which is always $\ge 1$.

For an $\epsilon$-$N$ argument that the limit of the $a_n$ is not $i$, choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.